# Email solutions for web application?

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have a PHP web application hosted on managed cloud server that doesn't provide mail server. I need two email addresses. One just for sending automated emails (Transaction email) and one for receiving and sending emails manually. What are my solutions? My application will send more than 500 emails per day.

Comment: Most cheap web hosting service offers come with a domain and an email package these days.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/)

Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail)

Comment: I will also need a separate email for sending and receiving emails. Mailgun is only a transactional email provider.

Comment: Ok, I see. If you have not got answer by tuesday I will revisit this question as will set that up for my own app then.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest:

1. Create a GMail AC enable POP3 email forwarding in the SETTINGS and you use the settings within the PHP code and you are done.

Best Solution:

1. Try large scale solutions (cloud based):
   sendgrid.com or mailgun.com they are best for large email blast.